# How do I express that a set of objects is numbered in ascending order starting from 0 with increments of 1?

Tags: phrase-requests

I need to express that a system is creating objects. The number of objects can be specified. And the objects are numbered from 0 to number of objects minus 1. How do I express that?

Example: The primary thread is creating a team of OpenMP threads. They are numbered in ascending order with the primary thread receiving the thread number 0.

My issue: An ascending order does not mean that the interval between the numbers in ascending order is 1. But I need to express that also. How can I do that in proper English?

Comment: Typically, you should wait a day or so before accepting an answer. In this domain-specific request, I suggest that the "other" answer would be better understood.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires very highly specialized domain-specific knowledge and therefore is not a question about English or its Usage. Please re-ask this on a programming-related SE site.

Comment: @Tchrist I read your profile, and I really enjoyed it. Way to go on your co-authoring of your book. I live in Sebastopol where the O'Reilly is located. On a more relative subject, I was wondering if there was any source that gives some sort of general description as to what an appropriate question for this site looks like?

Comment: @costrom  Your argument is fair, I accept that.  I generally had no words for what I wanted to express so the accepted answer was the best in general, even if the example on which I discovered my lacking knowledge was from a specific domain. Since I am not used to getting many answers I did not hesitate to accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest

> They are numbered **consecutively** from 0.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/consecutively) has

> **consecutively**
> <sub>ADVERB</sub>
>
> **1** One after another without interruption.
> **1.1** In unbroken or logical sequence.
> *the drives are just numbered consecutively*

I don't think you need to belabour it with *in ascending order*, but you would need to say *descending* if they were numbered `0` `-1` `-2` etc.

Answer (score 10):

For computer literate readers the phrase "[zero-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)" will convey this idea concisely.  The "indexing" part indicates that consecutive integers are used to label the items.

> The primary thread is creating a team of OpenMP threads, accessible using zero-based indexing.

Comment: This is also at times shorted to "zero-indexing" or "zero-indexed".

Comment: And in fact, within the specific domain of computer programming, this terminology is _so_ standard that if you don't use some variant of the phrase "zero-indexed", it might raise questions in some readers' minds about whether you were deliberately avoiding the phrase because you actually mean something different and unconventional.

Comment: Thank  you for your point of view @DavidZ. I mostly encountered that wording on arrays or similar data structures and did not find it in the documentation about the thing I work with, so this clarifies and helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## Enumerate (d, ing)

Enumerate (*pronounced:* **`e·nu·mer·ate`**) is the absolute correct word to use for situation described by the question.

Enumerate, in all of its forms (enumerates, enumerated, enumeration, and enumerating) is a word that's commonly found in computer science. Its used to describe a system (or algorithm) with the system/algorithm works in a particular way. It should be noted, the question asked by this posts author, describes a very simple algorithm. To offer a clear example, I have expressed the algorithm below

### `index = index + 1`

Each object in a group takes on a number, this is called the index-number. Every index-number is equal to the index-number that was assigned before it, plus one.

The name for this algorithmic-process is called **enumeration**.

The process of using an expressible repeating pattern, to increment a the index-numbers of object-groups, is called enumeration.

When ever a system increments a groups index number, using a pattern that repeats it is said that the system enumerates.

When a system enumerates a group of objects successfully, the processed group is said to have been **enumerated**.

When a group of objects is able to be enumerated, it is said to be **enumerable**.

Enumerate is not only a word used in Computer Science and Mathematics, it is often used in a more formal context as well. Below is the generic definition, non-specific to any academic-subject or science. I also included an example, used by someone not referencing anything computer science related. The purpose of outlined the generic use of Enumerate, is to show that even in a non math-related context, the word is still used to describe the process of `index = 1 + 1`.

---

##### [The formal definition —](https://www.dictionary.com/) *[which I obtained from Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/)* [— is as follows:](https://www.dictionary.com/)

> **Definition** — *To mention separately as if in counting; name one by one; specify, as in a list.*

---

###### [Here is a Merriam Webster provided example of Enumerate being used in a public article.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerate)

> **EXAMPLE:** *One historian, years ago, decided to collect and enumerate all the scholarly explanations for the fall of Rome.*
>
> ###### — Cullen Murphy, The Atlantic, 1 Mar. 2022

---

Comment: If it seems like I overly defined the word enumerate, or like my answer is too verbose, then you probably don't share the love for the English language that I do.

Comment: Outside of math and computer science, I'm not sure "enumerate" carries the implication of a specific order that the asker is going for.

Comment: @Nasch first of all, this question was closed because it request a very specific domain of knowledge. Which is an accurate reason for closing the question. As much as I enjoyed answering it, I felt like I was answering a question on Stack Overflow. He was asking to describe a system. Describing systems is the very essence of what a programming language does.

Comment: How would you suggest that this word be used? Would you suggest simply "The primary thread is creating a team of OpenMP threads. They are enumerated"? I think that's not adequate, because if I came across that in documentation, I wouldn't know what it means, and I would have several different guesses: I'd guess that maybe it means "they are listed explicitly somewhere in this documentation," or maybe "there is some process which occasionally makes a list of them," or maybe "they are assigned numbers in some unspecified fashion."